# How can I make an updatable function-map with an updatable condp inside of it?

Tags: clojure

I have two primary goals:

1.) `{:foo (fn ...)}` should be defined outside of the function-map in a way that allows you to update `:foo's (fn ...)` (perhaps a ref, but maybe? an atom)

2.) The cases for condp: `"fred", "ethel"` should live in a structure that can be updated as well.  For instance, if I want to add `"lucy" (handle-lucy a b c d)` to the condp I'd like to be able to do that by using a separate structure to hold all of the cases for the condp.  The trouble is that placing them in a map or a vector, for instance, means the variables a `b message and d` are not available within the context of that structure.

Summary: Help me refactor this to make `:foo` and `:bar` their own functions which live in `#'function-map` that can be updated while the program is running.  In addition, help me find a way to take the cases for the condp and put them into their own updatable container.

Summary 2: If you think what I'm asking for is crazy, take a whack at refactoring this however you see fit.  I'm mainly interested in generally increasing readability and accessibility.

This is a shortened version of the function-map that I am struggling to refactor

```
(def function-map
  {:foo (fn [{:keys [a b message d]}]
          (let [[command & args] (.split message " ")]
            (condp = command
                "fred" (handle-fred a b @d)
                "ethel" (handle-ethel a b (first args) @d)
                nil)))
   :bar (fn [{:keys [a b c]}]
          (do-something a b c))})
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Your obvious choices here are to make function-map a ref/atom containing a map OR to make the value for each key a ref/atom containing the function.  I can't judge from your description which makes more sense.  1 ref/atom is simpler but any change to the function-map will potentially create a transaction conflict for every other change.  I'm guessing this map isn't changing constantly but only occasionally, in which case 1 ref/atom would probably be sufficient.  Atoms are for uncoordinated synchronous change.  Refs are for coordinated (transactional) synchronous change.  If you need to change multiple functions together as part of a transaction or do compare-and-set type behavior, use a ref. Otherwise, use an atom.

2) For the condp part, it sounds to me like you want dynamic (polymorphic) behavior based on value.  To get that, don't use condp; use a multimethod with a dispatch function that utilizes the mutable state.  That will let you dynamically add cases (defmethods) without modifying the dispatch code.  If you want to "update" the set of commands after the fact, add a new defmethod whenever you want. If you want access to state at the time of handling, just pass it into the handler definition.

```
(defmulti handle-command (fn [command a b message d & args] command))
(defmethod handle-command "fred" [_ a b _ d] (handle-fred a b d))
(defmethod handle-command "ethel" [_ a b _ d [f & _]] (handle-ethel a b f d))

(def function-map
  {:foo (fn [{:keys [a b message d]}]
          (let [[command & args] (.split message " ")]
            (handle-command command a b message @d args)))})
```

Apologies on typos...not actually trying any of this at a repl.